# why PIG FILTER return nothing?

Tags: filter, count, apache-pig

Hi does somebody know why the FILTER command returns nothing in the following code? Thank u!

```
data = LOAD 'sample1.txt'
        AS (campaign_id:chararray,
         date:chararray, 
         time:chararray,
         keyword:chararray, 
         display_site:chararray, 
                 placement:chararray, 
         was_clicked:int, 
         cpc:int);

count1 = FOREACH (GROUP data ALL) GENERATE COUNT(data);
DUMP count1;


clicked = FILTER data BY (was_clicked==1);

DUMP clicked;
count2 = FOREACH (GROUP clicked ALL) GENERATE COUNT(clicked);
DUMP count2;
```

I tried `DUMP data` and see there are some records with (was_clicked==1).
`DUMP count1` displayed (100), which is as expected.

`DUMP clicked` displayed nothing.
`DUMP count2` displayed nothing.

I called the .pig file in local mode: `$ pig -x local analysis1.pig`

Comment: can you please paste the output of DUMP count1?

Comment: hi @GauravPhapale the output was (100). I checked the data again and found I used a wrong scheme for the data. Actually the last column but one was contry: chararray in the data, but I wrote was_clicked:int in the scheme. This was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt see any problem in the script. Its working fine. Can you paste your sample inputs?

```
input.txt  
aaa,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,2,100  
zzz,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100  
xxx,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100  
yyy,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,2,100  
jjj,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100  
kkk,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,4,100
```

PigScript:

```
data = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage(',')  
        AS (campaign_id:chararray,  
         date:chararray,  
         time:chararray,  
         keyword:chararray,  
         display_site:chararray,  
         placement:chararray,  
         was_clicked:int,  
         cpc:int);  
count1 = FOREACH (GROUP data ALL) GENERATE COUNT(data); 
dump count1; 
clicked = FILTER data BY (was_clicked==1);  
dump clicked;  
count2 = FOREACH (GROUP clicked ALL) GENERATE COUNT(clicked);  
dump count2;  

output of count1:  
(6)  

Output of clicked:  
(zzz,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100)  
(xxx,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100)  
(jjj,1234,5678,bbb,ccc,ddd,1,100)  

Output of count2:  
(3)
```

Comment: Hi @Sivasakthi Jayaraman I checked it again and found I put wrong description of the data in the LOAD command. The last but one column was chararray in my data. Sorry about the stupid question... (how did Pig LOAD chararray into int...)

Comment: @YZhang, It might be because Hadoop uses the schema definition for READ and not WRITE. This is just the opposite in RDBMS where Schema Definition is used for Write